# Metasploitable: vnc_login - doesn't work with msfadmin:msfadmin

Tags: authentication, metasploit, kali-linux

I am quite new to Metasploit and pen testing in general, so apologies for any seemingly noobish references below.

I am using `auxiliary/scanner/vnc/vnc_login`, after seeing that the 5900 port is open on Metasploitable. Furthermore, given that the credentials to log into Metasploitable are:

username - msfadmin
password - msfadmin

When I run the exploit with settings the IP to that of Metasploitable, and set the USERNAME and PASSWORD to "msfadmin" (and set THREADS to 50) whilst also including "msfadmin" as an entry in both the USER_FILE and PASS_FILE which I provided (in which I just appended "msfadmin" to the rockyou.txt file contained in `/usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt`).

Upon executing the exploit, for some reason I get success for the following:

```
[+] 192.168.XXX.XXX:5900 - LOGIN SUCCESSFUL: :password
```

Where is the username indicated in this? And why does (from my guess) the string "password" allow the exploit to authenticate?

Comment: I believe the output is saying that the username was null

Comment: I  am familiar with this one.  Try running Nessus on this port.  I do not want to spoil it for you...

Answer (score 1):

Vnc_login module provides in the mentioned format only. It simply means that the username is not required and the password is "password".

Answer (score 0):

You asked for the full guide for metasploitable and I hate to give you all the answers but if you are really stuck you can look up the full details of the exploitation of each and every way you can root the vulnerable os. Here is the website with the full guide and explanation. Remember, look up what you are stuck on getting the answers is not hacking. Some people take weeks to figure it out on their own its not made to be fully understood in a day. Anyway here is the website.

[Metasploitable Guide Walk-through](https://community.rapid7.com/docs/DOC-1875)

Comment: By the way like other have said vnc does not require and username to login, just a password, hence, you successfully cracked the correct password for vnc.